# Cannot find symbol message in this java program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I don't know why I am getting two errors, I think I'm close to getting the program where I want it to be. Can someone help me by telling what I need to do to get these errors gone. The other questions aren't specific to my issue and haven't helped.

```
    C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Java Work\Assignment2Tourist.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        month1[i] = input.nextInt();
                    ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class Assignment2Tourist

    C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Java Work\Assignment2Tourist.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
            month2[i] = input.nextInt();
                        ^
      symbol:   variable input
      location: class Assignment2Tourist
    2 errors

Process completed.
```

Assignment2Tourist:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2Tourist {

    public static void main (String [] arguments)
    {

    int[] month1 = new int[11];
    int[] month2 = new int[11];

    for (int i = 0; i < month1.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of vistors 2013-");
        month1[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < month2.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of vistors 2014");
        month2[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

        System.out.print("The average visitors for 2013 - ");
        avVisitors(month1);

        System.out.print("The average visitors for 2014 - ");
        avVisitors(month2);

        System.out.print("The most Visitors in 2013 were - ");
        highVisitors(month1);

        System.out.print("The most Visitors in 2014 were - ");
        highVisitors(month2);

        monthAverage(month2, month1);

    }
```

Comment: where did you declare input,

Comment: System.out.println("Please enter the amount of vistors 2013-");
    month1[i] = input.nextInt();  I thought I had done it here for 2013?

Comment: You have never declared input, it should be an instance of Scanner. check the below answers for examples.

Comment: Ok, thanks I did add the scanner, I got a few more errors, but they have been dealt with, I'm just beginner you see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is not declared.
Put that before your `for loop`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < month1.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of vistors 2013-");
    month1[i] = input.nextInt();
}
for (int i = 0; i < month2.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of vistors 2014");
    month2[i] = input.nextInt();
}
input.close();
```

and dont forgett to close the `Scanner` with `close()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing scanner object as input, you have not defined input variable.

```
public static void main (String [] arguments)
{
String s = "Number of visitor in 2013 was 123450";

int[] month1 = new int[11];

int[] month2 = new int[11];
Scanner input = new Scanner(s);
for (int i = 0; i < month1.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of vistors 2013-");
    month1[i] = input.nextInt();
}

for (int i = 0; i < month2.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of vistors 2014");
    month2[i] = input.nextInt();
}

    System.out.print("The average visitors for 2013 - ");
    avVisitors(month1);

    System.out.print("The average visitors for 2014 - ");
    avVisitors(month2);

    System.out.print("The most Visitors in 2013 were - ");
    highVisitors(month1);

    System.out.print("The most Visitors in 2014 were - ");
    highVisitors(month2);

    monthAverage(month2, month1);

}
```